# Trying to allocate elastic ip address leads to Not Found error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-ip

I have recently created a new AWS account for deploying some microservices my company uses on here. Our old account was destroyed. The issue is some old component uses a elastic IP that resolved to a box on our old account.

I am unable to reclaim that elastic ip from my new account. From the documentation i see that if that ip has been released, then one can claim it. I can verify it's not claimed since there's nothing running on it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t request a specific Elastic IP that has previously been allocated to *another account*. You can only reclaim your EIP that has accidentally been released from the same account and only for a limited time.

Obtain a **new Elastic IP** and **update your DNS**. Problem sorted :)